# How to get Active Directory Base DN from Down-Level logon name by ldap

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, ldap-query

Lets assume ve a Down-Level logon name like TEST\John (Domain\sAMAccountName)

Which i received via NTML SSO in my web application. Now i need to query the AD 
via LDAP to get some additional information.

In order to do that i need the UPN suffix - also known as the domain name - (e.g. test.foo.bar) to construct a base dn in the form DC=test,DC=foo,DC=far.

So is there 
a. a way to receive the UPN suffix from the Down-Level logon name via LDAP? 
or
b. A way to query with just the Down-Level logon name?

Thanks,
n.

Comment: You can easily do using step (b) - perform LDAP query based on sAMAccountname. Point (a) is unclear to me.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: nope i can not consinder local accounts  e.g. TEST\john vs PC1234\john (when not logged in with a domain account but a local one i get MASCHINENAME\account so thats not unique unforutnatly

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: further more -> no base dn no query at all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

The Domain Root Object is the DN for the DOMAIN and is the value of the [DefaultNamingContext](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156506.aspx) attribute in [RootDSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746462(v=vs.85).aspx) on each DC in **that** AD Domain.